# How to install openssh-server on my server?

Tags: debian, ssh, apt, dpkg, openssh

I want to install openssh-server on my server, but it shows me :

**apt-get install openssh-server**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart : Depends: ifupdown (>= 0.6.10ubuntu5)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when I try to  **`apt-get -f install`**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-numpy python-gobject-2 python-gobject-dev libpython2.7 docbook-xml
  docbook-xsl python-dev libgirepository-1.0-1 liblapack3gf libffi-dev
  libquadmath0 libffi5 python-gi libssl-dev python2.6-dev libglade2-0
  libblas3gf gir1.2-glib-2.0 python-gobject sgml-data libgfortran3
  python2.7-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ifupdown
Suggested packages:
  ppp rdnssd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ifupdown
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 325 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/48.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 43.0 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
y
Reading changelogs... Done
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
 plymouth depends on udev (>= 166-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 mountall depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initscripts:
 initscripts depends on upstart; however:
  Package upstart is not configured yet.
 initscripts depends on mountall (>= 2.28); however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plymouth
 mountall
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so I tried to install deb files with `dpkg -i --force-overwrite`
but again shows me error.

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze)
Release:    6.0.10
Codename:   squeeze
```

**apt-cache policy**

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main Translation-fr
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

any idea ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt-cache policy`? You seem to have a mixture of Debian and Ubuntu somehow.

Comment: Please add the output of the `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` .

Comment: You somehow managed to install the Ubuntu version of plymouth and upstart.  You need to install the Debian version instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try purging the installation and cleaning up apt a bit.

Try:

`sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client --purge && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get update`

If you don't have any reason not to upgrade packages then also try:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

You can then try installing the packages again to see if this resolved the issue:

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`

**Edit:**

Noticed that `ubuntu` is referenced in the error: `upstart : Depends: ifupdown (>= 0.6.10ubuntu5)`

Check your `sources.list` file and `sources.list.d` directory files for any references to `ubuntu`. If there are comment them out and try the above commands again.

If any `ubuntu` PPA's or `ubuntu` .deb packages are installed this could also cause issues.

Comment: Thats a shame - sorry I couldn't be of more help. Have you also tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` by any chance?

Comment: Hmm.. is your OS ubuntu or debian? There are a few references to ubuntu in those errors? Do you have any added PPA's or anything added to the `sources.list` file?

Comment: Yes, so there shouldn't be any references to `ubuntu` then? `upstart : Depends: ifupdown (>= 0.6.10ubuntu5)` and `debian squeeze` has `ifupdown_0.7.8` in it's repo it seems.

Comment: No problems. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

With special thanks to All of you I changed the `sources.list` to :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
```

and it worked, `oldstable` was important I think.